# Persistent locale-related errors and crashes

Tags: locale

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Chromebook via Chrubuntu, which doesn't appear to have set up locales correctly. My attempts to do so myself are failing. The system *should* be en_GB in UTF-8 mode. The output of `locale -a` includes `en_GB.utf8`. `locale` outputs the following:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8
LC_NUMERIC=en
LC_TIME=en
LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8
LC_MONETARY=en
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8
LC_PAPER=en
LC_NAME=en
LC_ADDRESS=en
LC_TELEPHONE=en
LC_MEASUREMENT=en
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en
LC_ALL=
```

Various programs throw locale-related errors, mostly non-fatal, for example:

```
(process:2711): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

However, I'm also getting crashes at bootup from Keyboard Input Methods and when attempting to use the Language Support section of System Settings. At present, my `/etc/default/locale` file reads as follows, which was copied from the `locale` output on a working system (though I might have made one or two changes since then):

```
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

At various points trying to fix this, I've managed to cause apt to throw 400 errors when trying to run `apt-get update`, and render the system entirely unbootable by causing `mountall` to crash.

I've tried various solutions I've found by Googling the problem, including running `locale-gen` and `dkpg-reconfigure locales`, with no luck.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Edit: So setting `LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8` fixes the local issues, but it causes a pile of error messages when I try and SSH into other machines that don't have en_GB.utf8 available. This doesn't happen on my other Ubuntu boxes, so there must be a way of getting the local settings sorted *without* setting `LC_ALL` and causing these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your `/etc/default/locale` looks correct, I recommend that you change it to just contain

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

(which in effect is the same thing).

But the problem seems to be that something in your user settings messes up the locale. I don't know anything about Chrubuntu, but assuming that you have access to the Ubuntu GUI for setting languages, I suggest that you go to `System Settings -> Language Support` and explicitly set both the language and the regional formats from there.

In any case, it's never ever a good idea to set LC_ALL via `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Chrubuntu is just some magic for getting Ubuntu installed and booting with Chromebooks' weird bootloader - it should be stock Ubuntu once installed. My Language Support settings are set to English (United Kingdom) on both Language and Regional Formats tabs. Setting that value in `/etc/default/locale` causes the errors described in the first post.

Comment: @Sam: What if you change the regional formats to something else, and then back to "English (United Kingdom)"? I suggest you do that, then log out and log in again, open a terminal window and run the `locale` command.

Comment: Wiping my `/etc/default/locale` and then doing that did fix it, thank you.

Comment: I've been dealing with the exact same issue for weeks. No answers out there worked for me. Finally, deleting `/etc/default/locale` and resetting my language as recommended worked. Thank you!